# Can I set exact value in a JSON Schema?

Tags: json, jsonschema

I use [JSON Schema](http://json-schema.org/) to validate app objects against some schema for testing.

I see that I can set `minimum` and `maximum` values for a property:

```
"responseCode": {
        "type": "integer",
        "minimum": 100,
        "maximum": 500
    }
```

But I couldn't find if I can set an exact required value, like `"value":123`.

Is it possible to set it to exactly what I need to validate for?

Comment: I am not sure if that is desirable but you could try to set the minimum = maximum = 123.

Comment: It works but quite verbose.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

You can:

```
{ "enum": [123] }
```

or

```
{ "const": 123 }
```

`const` is now part of draft-06 of [JSON schema specification](http://json-schema.org/draft/2019-09/json-schema-validation.html#rfc.section.6.1.3) (it is supported by [Ajv](https://github.com/epoberezkin/ajv/blob/master/KEYWORDS.md#constant-v5-proposal) and some other validators).

Answer (score 2):

In case anybody was wondering how to specify a string value rather than a number, especially in AWS API Gateway, which uses JSON Schema Draft-04, You can use regular expressions:

```
{
    "type": "string",
    "pattern": "MyStringOrOtherRegex"
}
```

https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-fge-json-schema-validation-00#section-3.3

Comment: This isn't necessary. `enum` and `const` work for strings (and any other type for that matter). Also, if you do this, make sure to anchor your regex with `^` and `$`. Otherwise something like `"pattern": "a"` will match "cat".

Comment: This is half correct.  "const" keyword does not appear to be available in Draft-04 (AWS will not accept it).

Comment: I just meant that `const` works with strings. I didn't mean to imply that `const` worked in draft-04. But, the way I wrote it was certainly confusing. Thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score -4):

Already mentioned but the 2 options I know are:

```
{ "enum": [123] }
```

and

```
{ "const": 123 }
```

My source was:
https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/generic.html

Keep up the good work!

Comment: I am sure you will perform well next time.

Comment: This answer does not add any additional value and seems to be a copy of the currently accepted answer.